# Stuck converting string into json

Tags: java, android

I just started with android development and I am facing a problem that I can't solve.

I call an API in my android app using `Volley` and I get the following response:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 25,
    "user_id": 39,
    "positionX": "51.4595484",
    "positionY": "5.4757402",
    "modified": "2016-12-15T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "user_id": 40,
    "positionX": "51.4595518",
    "positionY": "5.4757409",
    "modified": "2016-12-15T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "user_id": 41,
    "positionX": "51.459554",
    "positionY": "5.4757413",
    "modified": "2016-12-15T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "user_id": 42,
    "positionX": "51.459554",
    "positionY": "5.4757413",
    "modified": "2016-12-15T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

I am trying to fetch data from `JSONArray`, but I can't make it work... This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = jsonObject.getJSONObject();
            points.add(new LatLng(row.getDouble("positionX"),row.getDouble("positionY")));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated users info." + points.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: define *but I can't make it work* also *I am facing a problem that I can't solve.* what problem?

Comment: also, you'd probably benefit from using `gson` library

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: @Bonatti thanks! gonna check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to simply fetch your `row` from `JSONArray` instead of first `JSON` object so simply do this

1.) Create your `JSONAray`

2.) Traverse array and fetch `JSONObject` using index

3.) Fetch the data from `JSONObject` which was retrieved during 2nd step

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         points.add(new LatLng(row.getDouble("positionX"),row.getDouble("positionY")));
        }
```

**Improvement** : To avoid exceptions on missing keys and value use [optDouble](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.optDouble%28java.lang.String%29) which can handle missing values or values in form of string

Comment: Hey, when I try to use your code my application crashes. I am getting the following error: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Barteo you simply forgot to initialize your `points` list before using it so it should be `points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();` you can do it inside `oncreate` or make sure to do it before this loop

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
@Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject row= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)                               
                                points.add(new LatLng(row.getDouble("positionX"),row.getDouble("positionY")));
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated users info." + points.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
```

But I suggest you to use ***Gson Library*** to parse json it is best in business

Download  -http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm

How to add lib- [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

How to use it - https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/07/28/getting-started-with-google-gson/                Or  https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples